# how to add gnome bar network manager to awn?

Tags: gnome-panel, network-manager, awn

I love the network manager in the gnome panel but I don't want the gnome panel cause that is all I use it for.

This is more of a feature request than a question.

I know there is a network manager applet for awn in progress but isn't there another way to get the gnome panel network manager working from the avant window navigator dock???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your awn version doesn't support the systray applet, You need the testing ppa: [instructions](http://wiki.awn-project.org/DistributionGuides#Karmic_.289.10.29_and_later)
The actual version is 0.4.1.

Afterwards you can add "systray" to your dock (sorry my screenshot is only in german)

[image]

Comment: I have 0.4.1 but the applet is not loading. I quick the applet that was in the gnome panel. Still not loading in awn. I dragged the applet to my dock but it doesn't show up. I should maybe log in and out and check if there is a change.

Comment: bdr529- As I thought. I rebooted and the applet showed up. Thank you very much for the answer bdr529

Answer (score 2):

You can add both notification area and indicator applet to awn. Just go to applets section of AWN preference and add notification area and indicator applet. I think the network manager falls under notification tray rather  than indicator applet.

First remove notification area from panel and do the above steps.

[image]